# Remove title from static pages

Tags: wordpress, categories

On the site I'm working on I have two kind of pages:

1. A page containing posts from specific categories
2. Static pages

On the pages with categories I want the category name to show on top of the page, but on the static pages I don't want any title to show up at the top (other than the subject I choose when creating the page).

**Category page:**
[image]

**Static page:** <- "Blogg" shouldn't be there
[image]

So, how can I remove the title from static pages (always "blogg" which I don't know where it comes from)?

**EDIT:** I'm using a theme called "future" (http://wordpress.org/themes/future)

Comment: Are u using any template or default template?

Comment: @user2054372: I'm using a theme called "future"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change on page loop-meta.php.
Its coming from here.
Comment or remove this code

```
<?php //_e( 'Blog', 'future' ); ?>.
```